# Prove vector area formula by stokes's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, exterior-algebra, stokes-theorem

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_area) says the following two formulas are equivalent.
${\mathbf {S}}=\int d{\mathbf {S}}$
${\displaystyle \mathbf {S} ={\frac {1}{2}}\oint _{\partial S}{\vec {r}}\times d{\vec {r}}}$
I am learning exterior derivative and the generalized stokes' theorem ${\displaystyle \int _{\partial \Omega }\omega =\int _{\Omega }d\omega \,}$, but when I applied $d(r \wedge dr) = dr \wedge dr - r \wedge ddr= dr \wedge dr + 0 = 0 \Rightarrow S = 0$

where did I do wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You forgot that $\vec r$ is a vector. You need to work out the $1$-form in coordinates.

Comment: P.S. it is probably most helpful to compare $\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf S$ and the analogous dot product in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

From Stokes's Theorem along with the vector identity $\nabla \times (\hat x_i\times\vec A )=\hat x_i \nabla \cdot \vec A-(\hat x_i\cdot \nabla)\vec A $, we have

$$\begin{align}
\hat x_i\cdot \oint_{\partial S}\vec r\times d\vec r&=\oint_{\partial S}(\hat x_i\times  \vec r)\cdot d\vec r\\\\
&=\int_S \hat n\cdot \nabla\times (\hat x_i\times\vec r)\,dS\\\\
&=\int_S \hat n\cdot (2\hat x_i)\,dS\\\\
&=2\hat x_i\cdot \int_S \hat n\,dS
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment??

Comment: I guess due to you not using differential froms. I thought it was good answer tho. Upvote from me